# How to automatically do feature extraction of time series data for a regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, feature-engineering

**Abstract question :** In a regression problem, what methods are there to embed a varying-length time series into a fixed-length vector summarizing the data without hand-crafting the features ? Is there a principled way to achieve this given the regression problem to solve? This is not a problem of forecasting a time series but rather use a varying-length time series data as an input to an otherwise standard regression problem where a matrix **X** predicts a real-valued target **y**. From my understanding, since it's a regression problem, not all features will perform equally well, therefore it is in principle possible to extract the most optimal ones.

**Concrete example :** I want to build an ML model to predict (regression) the yield of different crops from different features, including the daily weather (average temperature, rainfall, ...) between the sowing date (**A**) to the harvest date (**B**). Since the number of days (**B - A**) between the two dates can vary for each input, I need to transform the time series into an array of fixed size *N* without handcrafting or choosing the features themselves (like *min*, *max*, *mean*, *std*, ...). From the scientific literature, I have found some of the most used hand-crafted features, but found them very simple and want to know if it's possible to discover better ones. Another way of framing the question is to ask the following : let say that we know that the most important feature for explaining yield is the number of consecutive days above 35°C/100°F (arbitrary threshold) during the period between **A** and **B**. Is there a way to automatically reverse-engineer this specific feature ? Of course, this is an example of a simple feature, but the "true" optimal features could be arbitrarily complex. Finally, the feature would not be written in natural language, but would be a neural network or some other complex function that I could study to understand and eventually translate into natural language.

Comment: One other way is to use lstms to encode the series and then feed it to the rest of the network.